# Counting Sublist Elements in Prolog

Tags: prolog

How can I count nested list elements in Prolog?
I have the following predicates defined, which will count a nested list as one element:

```
length([ ], 0).
length([H|T],N) :- length(T,M), N  is  M+1.
```

Usage:

```
?- length([a,b,c],Out).
Out = 3
```

This works, but I would like to count nested elements as well i.e.

```
length([a,b,[c,d,e],f],Output).
?- length([a,b,[c,d,e],f],Output).
```

Output = 6

Comment: Hi Shaggy, I am using prolog in my course, however this isn't a direct homework question. I plan to implement something like this in a future project though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
len([H|T],N) :-
    len(H, LH),
    len(T, LT),
    !,
    N is LH + LT.
len([], 0):-!.
len(_, 1):-!.
```

Test:

```
?- len([a,b,[c,d,e],f],Output).
Output = 6.
```

Comment: `len([],1)` succeeds.

Comment: was wondering if you could better explain the cut for me? I understand it has saying only match the H, T, LH, LT multiple times. I wrote something exactly similar without the cut and it gives me an overflow im assuming it takes too much memory backtracking and etc. Is my intuition right?

Comment: I think you are right. Cut when executed cancels backtracking. It means if
    `len(H, LH),
    len(T, LT),` succeeds, and ! crossed - it won't retry to success them again.